# Converting Mongoose MPromise into Rxjs.Observable in TypeScript

Tags: mongoose, typescript, promise

I want to convert MPromise which is used by mongoose - https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise into Observable Rxjs.Observable. Could you share your opinion on the following code snippet. Is it good enough?

```
export function fromMPromise<T>(m: mongoose.Promise<T>): Rx.Observable<T> {
    const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject<T>(1);
    m.onFulfill((v: T) => {
        subject.next(v);
        subject.complete();
    });
    m.onReject((e: any) => {
        subject.error(e);
        subject.complete();
    });
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Not sure why you use a `const` though. Take a look at the RXJS implementation: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/9d6ea94244c2f40a29373f9ed6b12d951d3f2238/src/modular/observable/frompromise.js#L30

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-observables

Comment: maybe this can work for you [RXJS Observable from mongoose (mongodb)](https://gist.github.com/wellcaffeinated/f908094998edf54dc5840c8c3ad734d3)